# ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated, do i need to add quote on the phone number, why?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-insert, create-table

```
SQL> create table customer(
  2  customer_ID number(3) primary key,
  3  customer_Name varchar2(26),
  4  contact_Name  varchar2(26),
  5  phone number(10));

Table created.

SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMER_ID                               NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 CUSTOMER_NAME                                      VARCHAR2(26)
 CONTACT_NAME                                       VARCHAR2(26)
 PHONE                                              NUMBER(10)
SQL> insert into customer 
        (customer_ID, customer_Name, contact_Name, phone) 
        values (23, 'Dave's Sub Shop', 'David Logan', 555-333-4545);
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

Can anyone explain this error for me?

Comment: Its this:    'Dave's Sub Shop'   you have a quote inside your quoted string causing it to think Dave is what you are trying to insert for customer_Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here :

- you are inserting a string that contains an embedded single quote : `'Dave's Sub Shop'`. The glitch shows up in any decent text editor (including SO's). You need to escape the quote : `'Dave''s Sub Shop'`
- the `phone_number` column is declared as `number(10)`, however what you are trying to insert does not look like one : `555-333-4545`. You should change the column datatpe to `varchar(12)`. Then you will need to quote the values that you insert.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5899d5ea5fe2a230c62c7e72594dcd4a)** :

```
create table customer(
    customer_ID number(3) primary key,
    customer_Name varchar2(26),
    contact_Name  varchar2(26),
    phone varchar(12));

insert into customer 
        (customer_ID, customer_Name, contact_Name, phone) 
        values (23, 'Dave''s Sub Shop', 'David Logan', '555-333-4545');

1 rows affected

select * from customer;

CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME   | CONTACT_NAME | PHONE       
----------: | :-------------- | :----------- | :-----------
         23 | Dave's Sub Shop | David Logan  | 555-333-4545
```

NB : another solution would be to convert the phone number to a number datatype before inserting it (by removing the embedded `-` for example), but I would not recommend it, since phone numbers are actually *not* numbers : they may have meaningful leading zeros, and may contain non-digit characters (`()`, `+`, ...)

Comment: thanks, it works, but number  '555-333-4545' does not need the quote, add quote will be another error. what id i want make phone number become (555)333-4545, I try this there show is error too.

Comment: @YongmingLiu - "quote the value" means to enclose it in quotes; single quotes in this case. `555-333-4545` is not a number; you have to treat that, or `(555)333-4545`, as strings - by putting them in single quotes, and making sure the column you're storing them is `varchar2` and large enough to hold the longest value you might want to store. Your new value is now 13 characters, so you'll need at least `varchar2(13)`.

Comment: I got it, really appreciate.

Comment: I would just add my thumbs-up to @GMB comment about NOT storing phone numbers as NUMBER.  I was already forumulating my comment on that before I read his.  Our lives (and data) are full of "numbers" that aren't numbers - telephone, Social Security, Vehicle Identification.  My rule of thumb is, "if doing arithmetic on it is illogical, then it ain't a number, so declare it as a varchar2 and treat it as such."

Comment: Thanks for the comment @EdStevens !

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
insert into customer (customer_ID, customer_Name, contact_Name, phone) 
    values (23, 'Dave''s Sub Shop', 'David Logan', '555-333-4545');
```

Your error is due to "Dave's Sub Shop".  The first quote is taken as the end of the string, so the error occurs at the `s`.

The `555-333-4545` won't necessarily generate an error.  But it will produce the number -4323, which is not what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the apostrophe in Dave's Sub Shop.